# get element source focus angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, kendo-ui-angular2

**How to get element on focus.**

```
<kendo-autocomplete (focus)="relationsFocusAutoComplete($event.target)" 
 [(ngModel)]="vehicle.relation" name="relation-{{i}}">
</kendo-autocomplete>
```

**Component**

```
relationsFocusAutoComplete(value: any) {
   console.log(value); //This is throws target undefined error
}
```

> **Error**: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

i have tried like this

```
<kendo-autocomplete (focus)="relationsFocusAutoComplete($event)" 
 [(ngModel)]="vehicle.relation" name="relation-{{i}}">
</kendo-autocomplete>

 relationsFocusAutoComplete(value: any) {
   console.log(value); //This is also undefined
}
```

*This is [Kendo-Autocomplete](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/AutoCompleteComponent/) is generated in a `*ngFor` if needed i will include section*

[Issue in plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CuzLfzzfiDblDELpKvtL?p=preview)

[Kendo-Autocomplete](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/api/AutoCompleteComponent/)

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to get the element on focus

Comment: what if there is no value?

Comment: Will be there a case. I'm new to this .

I'm focusing on a element, so will be case where its null. I wish to get the element itself or its id in focus event.

Comment: you can use valuechange if you really want to get the value on change

Comment: value change will only trigger when i change the value of selection in dropdown.

Comment: My requirement is open the dropdown when user focus on it.

Comment: @Eldho you mean show another dropdown or the autocomplete dropdown?

Comment: Same dropdown. The requirement is like they should feel like combo box. when it focus automaticall open up and autocomplete allows to search.

Comment: @Eldho check my answer with plunker , you can use the toggle() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a template variable to access the autocomplete component and use `toggle()` method to show the autocomplete dropdown on `focus` and hide it on `blur` with the below code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
 <kendo-autocomplete #auto
     [data]="listItems"
     [placeholder]="placeholder"
     (focus)="auto.toggle()"
 >
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public placeholder: string = 'Type "it" for suggestions';
  public listItems: Array<string> = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"];


}
```

link for fiddle : 
https://plnkr.co/edit/b5jJxx1xsPpjSZEW93wq?p=preview

edit : for multiple autocomplete components with *ngFor you can use below , not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `

     <kendo-autocomplete *ngFor="let member of inputs;" #auto
     [data]="listItems"
     [placeholder]="placeholder"
     (focus)="auto.toggle()">
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public placeholder: string = 'Type "it" for suggestions';
  public listItems: Array<string> = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"];
  public inputs : any = ['first item','second item','third item','fourth item'];


}
```

Edit 2 : The error you mentioned in plunker is mostly due to a syntax check issue in plunker itself

you can use the below template . Actually plunker expects a closing `</kendo-autocomplete>` selector tag for the autocomplete before the closing `<div>` tag.

```
   <div *ngFor="let item of inputs; let i = index">
        <kendo-autocomplete #auto [data]="listItems" 
           [placeholder]="placeholder" (focus)="auto.toggle()">
        </kendo-autocomplete>
    </div>
```

updated plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/2teVCt94w3Es0lzyQWMX?p=preview

Comment: One more doubt my autocompletes are dynamic generated . `#relationAutocomplete{{i}}` How would i access this in focus

i tried this `(focus)="relationAutocomplete{{i}}.toggle()"`

Comment: Its like a div and couple of inputs with autocomplete box, i wil update it

Comment: It has a compile error https://plnkr.co/edit/gx6VjFgCOdrDkU1tdfAM?p=preview

Comment: @Eldho can you use *ngFor directly on kendo ui like i did above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161891/discussion-between-eldho-and-niladri).

Comment: But in my case i have set of inputs in in row.

Comment: @Eldho check the update, it's an issue with closing tag for plunker

Comment: thanks it worked perfect. i was thinking like we need a unique for each element. Thanks for ur time